# Laravel resource collection - paginate - JSON response error

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-5

I want to do paging at the Laravel API. As a result, I want to get data and status code type.

Controller :

```
public function index()
{
    $data = PersonCollection::collection(Person::paginate(2));

    return response()->json($data, 200);
}
```

PersonCollection Resource :

```
    public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'id' => $this->id,
        'first_name' => $this->first_name,
        'last_name' => $this->last_name,
        'email' => $this->email,
        'phone' => $this->phone,
        'city' => $this->city,
        'href' => [
            'link' => route('person.show', $this->id),
        ],
    ];
}
```

*Output :*

https://i.hizliresim.com/LvlBzj.png

```
[
{
"id": 1,
"first_name": "Burak Ali",
"last_name": "Ildır",
"email": "burak@gmail.com",
"phone": "376.395.7233",
"city": "Koelpinstad",
"href": {
"link": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v2/person/1"
}
},
{
"id": 2,
"first_name": "Vena",
"last_name": "Spinka",
"email": "shields.carolyn@example.org",
"phone": "716-268-7788 x092",
"city": "South Gudrunbury",
"href": {
"link": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v2/person/2"
}
}
]
```

---

**But I want.**

https://i.hizliresim.com/LvlBWo.png

```
{
"data": [
{
"id": 1,
"first_name": "Burak Ali",
"last_name": "Ildır",
"email": "burak@gmail.com",
"phone": "376.395.7233",
"city": "Koelpinstad",
"href": {
"link": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v2/person/1"
}
},
{
"id": 2,
"first_name": "Vena",
"last_name": "Spinka",
"email": "shields.carolyn@example.org",
"phone": "716-268-7788 x092",
"city": "South Gudrunbury",
"href": {
"link": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v2/person/2"
}
}
],
"links": {
"first": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/person?page=1",
"last": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/person?page=26",
"prev": null,
"next": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/person?page=2"
},
"meta": {
"current_page": 1,
"from": 1,
"last_page": 26,
"path": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/person",
"per_page": 2,
"to": 2,
"total": 52
}
}
```

**I want other page links. But when I convert it to JSON data, links and metadata do not come.**

Comment: And this is exactly why you should include the code instead of links to pictures of the code. Your links are now 403 to me

Comment: I just added it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A resource collection describes how a collection of models will be transmitted as JSON.

You seem to be using it for an individual model. What you need is:

```php
public function toArray($request)
{
    return $this->collection->map(function ($person) {
        return [
            'id' => $person->id,
            'first_name' => $person->first_name,
            'last_name' => $person->last_name,
            'email' => $person->email,
            'phone' => $person->phone,
            'city' => $person->city,
            'href' => [
                 'link' => route('person.show', $person->id),
            ],
        ];
    });

}
```

However the recommended way is to make a `PersonResource` instead in the same namespace and implement the `toArray($request)` in that class:

**Person**

```php
class Person extends Resource //The name is important
{
    public function toArray($request)
    {
       return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'first_name' => $this->first_name,
            'last_name' => $this->last_name,
            'email' => $this->email,
            'phone' => $this->phone,
            'city' => $this->city,
            'href' => [
                 'link' => route('person.show', $this->id),
            ],
        ];
    }
}
```

**PersonCollection**

```php
class PersonCollection extends ResourceCollection
{ 
   // This class is intentionally empty
}
```

Finally you should let Laravel handle how to make the response:

```php
public function index()
{
    $data = PersonCollection::collection(Person::paginate(2));

    return $data->toResponse();
}
```

The default behaviour of the resource collection is to look for a resource which is named like the collection but with the `Collection` part removed (in this case `PersonCollection` will look for a `Person` resource).

This should ensure each model is converted according to the resource and the pagination behaviour is maintained.